# Not able to make a table using tkinter (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am a complete newbee and trying to learn some python.
Was trying to create a Table using the tkinter module but this is what I am running into:
(I am trying to see if the Table class can successfully instantiate a visual table object with the supplied/default parameters)

The Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Table :
## contructor with the attributes
        def__init__(self,window,color='black',net_color='green',width=600,height=400,vertical_net=False,horizontal_net=False):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.color=color

my_table = Table(window)
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "table.py", line 13, in <module>
    my_table = Table(window)
NameError: name 'window' is not defined
```

Greatly appreciate any help that comes my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `window` hasn't been defined and is never opened. You can fix this by doing this:

1) Add this line before the `my_table = Table(window)` line:

```
window = Tk() #create the window
```

2) Add this line after the `my_table  = Table(window)` line:

```
window.mainloop() #open the window
```

Also, there is a space missing before the `__init__()`

Comment: Thank You. realised my conceptual fault here.